# IBM HTTP Server (IHS) Reverse Proxy and SSL

Tags: apache-2.4, ihs

I need to create an IHS reverse proxy that takes https://server1:6883 and proxies it to https://server2:6883, but unlike other ServerFault questions, the initial connection needs to be https not http. I have the following...

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
Listen 6883
<VirtualHost *:6883>
SSLEnable

SSLProxyEngine On
KeyFile /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/cert/wlpkey.kdb
ProxyPass / https://server2:6883/
</VirtualHost>
```

but error_log says:
SSL0227E: SSL Handshake Failed, Specified label could not be found in the key file. Label='(null)'

I suspect the problem is that I need two KeyFiles: one for proxy recipient and one to enable SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your certificate database has the needed certificate you need another directive called SSLServerCErt to tell the SSL virtualhost which certificate it must use for the SSL handshake, for example:

```
SSLServerCert server1.example.com
```

where server1.example.com is the label and the CN of the certificate you have in the keystorage database. Note you need the complete set of certificate, that is, the equivalent of a p12, a private key, a signed certificate and the CA chain.

Also, always add ServerName, specially if you have more than one single virtualhost, it is a good practice nevertheless.

```
ServerName server1.example.com
```